# Изменение имени столбца

Tags: sql, sql-server

В таблице необходимо изменить имя столбца. Как сделать? Использую ALTER TABLE [NAME_TABLE], а дальше всё перепробовал - выдаёт ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_rename 'TableName.OldColumnName' , 'NewColumnName', 'COLUMN';
```

Подробнее: [Rename Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), [sp_rename](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
Статья: [How to Rename a Column Name or Table Name](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/).

Comment: `EXEC sp_rename 'sample.customers.city', 'town', 'COLUMN`
Ошибка: "Либо задан сомнительный параметр objname, либо требуемый objtype (COLUMN) является ошибочным."

Comment: @Alex проверьте синтаксис, я проверил для всех версий  MS SQL что у меня есть под рукой, как вы выполняете скрипт?

Comment: Я явно указал имя БД sample - в этом и была ошибка. Спасибо.